# Discord.py отслеживание роли по нажатию на реакцию

Tags: python, discord.py

Бот должен чекать роль пользователя по реакции, но он почему-то триггерит только свои сообщения и работает нормально, но когда живой человек нажимает на реакцию, он выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pybot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pybot\main.py", line 38, in on_raw_reaction_add
    add_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=906203003479015484)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Как это можно исправить? Код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    channel_id = payload.channel_id
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    user_id = payload.user_id
    member = channel.guild.get_member(user_id)
    add_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=906203003479015484)
    for role in member.roles:
        if role.name != 'admin':
            await member.add_roles(add_role)
```

Comment: Если поправить member, тогда выйдет другая ошибка:

Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pybot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pybot\main.py", line 38, in on_raw_reaction_add
    for role in member.roles:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'

Answer (score 0):

```
member = discord.utils.get(channel.guild.members, id=user_id)
add_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=906203003479015484)
for role in member.roles:
    if role.name != 'admin':
        await member.add_roles(add_role)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]